# jqGrid set URL to custom button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I have a *jqGrid* in which I am trying to implement a *custom button* which will send request to *Servlet*.

So far I have done this:

```
.navButtonAdd('#pager10',
{
    caption:"Activate  ",
    buttonicon:"ui-icon-add",
    position:"last",
    mtype: 'POST',
    url: 'MyServletName',
    Data: {action: 'Activate',custID: function () {return custID;}},
    onClickButton: function()
    { 
        alert("Activate "+custID);
    },
});
```

Above code adds `Activate` button to the `pager` and also shows the alert from `onClickButton` event. But it doesn't send request to the *Servlet*.

So my question is that how should I set `URL` to a *custom button in jqGrid*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom button added to navigator bar with respect of [navButtonAdd](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_buttons) allows *to execute any JavaScript code* when the user click on the button. So you can implement *any* action which you need. For example you can use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to sent any information to the servlet or to assign new value to `location.href` to redirect to another URL. If needed you can get the rowid of currently selected row using the code like

```js
var rowid = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");
```

inside of `onClickButton`. So you can really implement any behavior which you need.